# Compute the coordinate vector with respect to the basis $(1,x-1, \dots (x-1)^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, binomial-theorem

Let $n$ be a natural number and $f$ be a polynomial with $\deg(f)\leq n$. We consider the basis
$$
\mathcal{B} = (1, x-1, (x-1)^2, \dots, (x-1)^n)
$$
of the vector space with all polynomials with degree less or equal $n$.

> **Question**: How does the coordinate vector of $f$ look like?

**Approach**:

- Let $f = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, i.e. the coefficients of $f$ are the $a_k$'s. Then $(f)_\mathcal{E}  = (a_0,\dots,a_n)$ where $\mathcal{E} = (1,x, \dots, x^n)$ is the monomial basis. I also know that $(f(t-1))_\mathcal{B} = (a_0,\dots,a_n)$.
- Since we are considering the terms $(x-1)^k$ for $k=0,\dots,n$, it might be useful to use the binomial theorem to obtain
  $$
  (x-1)^k = \sum_{\ell=0}^k \binom{k}{\ell}x^{k-\ell}(-1)^\ell.
  $$
  It would be nice if I could obtain a closed formula.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Write $f = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_{k} (x -1)^{k}$. Evaluate at $x = 1$ and get $a_{0} = f(1)$. Then differentiate and evaluate at $x = 1$ and get $a_{1} = f'(1)$. Repeating this process, you will get $a_{k} = \frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k !}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
$$
f(x)=f(1+(x-1))=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(x-1)^j\\
=\sum_{0\le j\le k\le n} a_k\binom{k}{j}(x-1)^j
=\sum_{j=0}^n(x-1)^j\sum_{k=j}^na_k\binom{k}{j}
$$